# How to add threads during run of program in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am adding threads as user wants. It means I stdin and if he wants new thread I create it. User give specific name to thread so I can not create it sooner than he wants.
Part of my code:

```
while(read != EOF) {
    if(user_wants_new_thread) {

        worker_t *data = malloc(sizeof(worker_t));

        data->name  = malloc((strlen(arg1) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(data->name, arg1);

        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, worker, (void *) data);
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    }
}
```

Thread should start to work without waiting. Now it waits for finishing of worker function.
Thank you for help :)

Comment: It's almost certainly a mistake to call `pthread_join()` immediately after `pthread_create()`.

Comment: If you call pthread_join(), you will be stuck until the thread is finished. If you want to synchronize with the startup of the thread you should use pthread_barrier_init(), pthread_barrier_wait()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when I use `pthread_join(thread, NULL);` it will wait till end of created thread. So it's necessary to delete this line.